# Changing Element Colour on Hover AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm just getting started with angularjs and I'm already confused. I want to change the colour of a list element that corresponds to a hex code colour that is in an array. I've tried some stuff but I just can't get it.

Here's my code so far:
HTML

```
<div id="mainContentWrap" ng-app="newApp">
 <div id="personContainer" ng-controller="personController">
<ul id="personList">
    <li class="bigBox no_s" ng-style="personColour"  ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-hover="changeColor()">< href="#/{{i.person_id}}">{{i.person_name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var app=angular.module('newApp',[]);
app.controller('personController',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $rootScope.persons=[
        {person_id:'0',person_name:'Jim',colour:"cc0000"},
        {person_id:'4',person_name:'Bob',colour:"f57900"},
        {person_id:'2',person_name:'James',colour:"4e9a06"},
        {person_id:'9',person_name:'Paul',colour:"3465a4"},
        {person_id:'3',person_name:'Simon',colour:"77507b"}
    ];
    $scope.changeColor(){
        $scope.personColour=$scope.persons.color// not sure what to do here???
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no `ng-hover` directive. You'll want to use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave`.

Also, keep in mind that the syntax for `ng-style` is an object corresponding the CSS key-value pairs.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-style="personColour" ng-mouseenter="changeColor(i)"></li>
```

```
$scope.changeColor = function(person) {
    $scope.personColour = {color: '#'+person.colour};
};
```

If you'd like for the color to change back to what it was before you hovered, you can create two functions, or pass a parameter to `$scope.changeColour`:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-style="personColour" ng-mouseenter="changeColor(i,true)" ng-mouseleave="changeColor(i,false)"></li>
```

```
$scope.changeColor = function(person, bool) {
    if(bool === true) {
        $scope.personColour = {color: '#'+person.colour};
    } else if (bool === false) {
        $scope.personColour = {color: 'white'}; //or, whatever the original color is
    }
};
```

---

## To take it a step further

You could create a directive for each person.

```
<person ng-repeat="i in persons"></person>
```

```
// your module, then...
.directive('person', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<li class="bigBox no_s"><a href="#/{{i.person_id}}">{{i.person_name}}</a></li>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            elm
                .on('mouseenter',function() {
                    elm.css('color','#'+i.colour);
                })
                .on('mouseleave',function() {
                    elm.css('color','white');
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to <strike>hack</strike> stay in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3]" ng-style="{ 'background': (isHover ? '#ccc' : 'transparent') }" ng-mouseenter="isHover = true;" ng-mouseleave="isHover = false;">
 <span>{{ n }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**in the code bellow i add easy code to understand how to active style with condition. I hope that help you**

```
<li ng-style="( (isOver == 'true') && (linkToActive == 'm1')  ) ? { 'background-color': '#00bdcb' } : {'background-color': '#ededed'}"
ng-mouseenter="vm.changeColorMenu('m1','true')" ng-mouseleave="vm.changeColorMenu('m1','false')">
</li>

<li ng-style="( (isOver == 'true') && (linkToActive == 'm2')  ) ? { 'background-color': '#00bdcb' } : {'background-color': '#ededed'}"
ng-mouseenter="vm.changeColorMenu('m2','true')" ng-mouseleave="vm.changeColorMenu('m2','false')">
</li>

</ul>
```

Javascript Code

```
function changeColorMenu(indexMenu,bool)
    {
        $scope.isOver = bool;
        $scope.linkToActive = indexMenu;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check an example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) you will see that ng-style directive waits for css style, not just value, so in your case it'll be:

```
$scope.person.colourStyle={'background-color':$scope.persons.color}
```

and in html it'll be:

```
<li class="bigBox no_s" ng-style="i.colourStyle"  ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-hover="changeColor()">< href="#/{{i.person_id}}">{{i.person_name}}</a></li>
```

**edit:**

And You also need to set colour value to full hex for example: '#cc0000'.

Comment: Sorry for additional edits. Just don't get full scope for problem when start answering.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, there is not `ng-hover` directive, so you should use `ng-mouseenter` & `ng-mouseleave` to simulate it.

```
<ul id="personList">
    <li class="bigBox no_s" ng-style="personColour" 
        ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-mouseenter="changeColor($index)" 
        ng-mouseleave="recoverColor($index)">
            <a href="#/{{i.person_id}}">{{i.person_name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you should use `$index` to get your element in persons Array

```
$scope.changeColor = function() {
    $scope.personColour = { 'color': '#' + $scope.persons[$index].color };
                           // or 'background-color' whatever you what
}

$scope.recoverColor = function() {
    $scope.personColour = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[See Plunker Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X6zN9dxpnUHTiSmZyXOJ?p=preview)

Use ng-style to conditionally apply CSS styles - I've chosen to name this style `'personStyle'`.  Next, bind the ng-mouseover event to set the `personStyle` background-color to the person's colour attribute. Finally, bind the ng-mouseleave event to reset the `personStyle` when the mouse leaves the element.  The changeColor() function is not needed for this solution to work.

```
<div id="personContainer" ng-controller="personController">
  <ul id="personList"> 
    <li class="bigBox no_s" ng-repeat="i in persons" ng-style="personStyle">
      <a href="#/{{i.person_id}}" ng-mouseleave="personStyle={}" 
             ng-mouseover="personStyle={ 'background-color':'#' + i.colour}">
             {{i.person_name}}</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```