# Changing color of active tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fairly new to AngularJS and I'm also using Bootstrap CSS.

I have a main page and I'm using ngRoute to load html templates.
I want the active navigation tab to change color whenever new template is loaded

I have something like

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li> 
      .....

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller  : 'mainCtrl',
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'about.html',
        controller  : 'mainCtrl',
    })
```

I've seen some answers where you dynamically add/remove 'active' class and yes that worked for me but I want custom color.

I generate a random color and save it in $scope.randomColor. I want to use that color as active color.

I have a directive that simply changes the color for active and hover. I wish I could just add and remove those to anchor tags based on which page a user is looking at.

```
.directive('ngHover', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        element
        .on('mouseenter',function() {
            element.css('color', scope.backgroundColor);
        })
        .on('mouseleave',function() {
            element.css('color','#333');
        });
    }
  }
})
.directive('ngActive', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        element.css('color', scope.backgroundColor);
    }
  }
});
```

Anyone have an idea how to achieve what I want to do? It seems so easy to do with Jquery but I'm learning Angular so I want to use that only if possible.

**Edit**

I tried adding 'active' class method but also changed the color of active class

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("active");    
var wrappedEl = angular.element(el);
wrappedEl.css('color', $scope.backgroundColor)
```

This seems to work but whenever I go to different tab, active class is removed from but color remains the same? weird..

**EDIT2**

Oh wait that was dumb lol
Solved it by adding style manually like suggested here

[Dynamically change a css class' properties with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918458/dynamically-change-a-css-class-properties-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Use ngstyle, here is the documentation;
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: I've looked into ngstyle already but I'm not sure how it can help me.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224753/changing-element-colour-on-hover-angularjs